# How to set a custom logs to S3 with AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment with some amazon linux instances running multi docker.
I have enabled log rotation from the beanstalk console and I can see the logs getting published to S3 every hour.

I want to change this default S3 path( `elasticbeanstalk-aws-region-xxxxx/resources/environments/logs/publish/yyyyy/i-zzzzz` ) to `my-bucket/eb/apps/logs`.

How do I set a cutom path?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I set a cutom path?

You can't change it. Its name is fixed for EB service in general.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I understand the specs of EB.

I'll look into other options.

Comment: @tadamw No problem. The acceptance of the answer would be appreciated as it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

The default path where it gets saved to the Elastic Beanstalk bucket is fixed but you can perform so post-processing in a Lambda to copy them to any bucket structure you want.

The high-level steps are:

1. Create a lambda with appropriate execution role permissions to read/write to the source and destination buckets.
2. Have the lambda copy logs from the beanstalk bucket to your destination bucket.
3. Create a CloudWatch event to trigger the lambda on a schedule.